# GridView renders unexpectedly when ItemsPanel is set to Grid

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have the following GridView on a Page:

```
<GridView Background="Black">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.Items>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hello"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="there"/>
    </GridView.Items>
</GridView>
```

This renders both "Hello" and "there" on top of each other in the upper left quadrant. I would have expected to find the word "Hello" in the upper left quadrant and "there" in the lower right quadrant.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? It's obvious that `TextBlock` won't get `Row` & `Column` as they are not the children of `Grid` but they are children of `GridView`.

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens of you say... set a fixed Height/Width on your Row/Column Definitions? Does it display more like expected then?

Comment: @Xyroid: What good is the possibility to specify a Grid as an ItemsPanelTemplate, when I can't really use the most basic Grid functionality for the items in the Grid? I want to achieve what I described as the expected behavior.

Comment: @Chris W.: I get the same results with fixed widths/heights.

Comment: @Xyroid It's not as obvious as you think. The TextBlock elements are not *children* of the GridView. They are added to the GridView's `Items` collection. Each of them is then put into the `Content` property of an automatically created GridViewItem, which in turn is added as a child to the ItemsPanel, i.e. the Grid here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework will automatically create a GridViewItem to contain each item in the GridView, unless you explicitly create one. Setting `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` on the contained item will therefore be ineffective. Try this instead:

```
<GridView Background="Black">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.Items>
        <GridViewItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="there"/>
        </GridViewItem>
    </GridView.Items>
</GridView>
```